Newton forward and Forward Euler method
in the article "Numerical studies on 2-dimensional reaction-diffusion equations" (Tang/Qin/Weber 1993?) i found the following:
we look for $u(x, y, t)$ satisfying
$$
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\lambda_1 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\lambda_2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+\mu u(1-u), \quad t>0, \quad(x, y) \in \Omega$$
$$
u(x, y, 0)=u^0(x, y), \quad 0 \leq u^0 \leq 1, \quad(x, y) \in \Omega_0 \subset \Omega, 
u=0, \quad t>0, \quad(x, y) \in \partial \Omega$$
where $\Omega=\{(x, y):|x|<a,\,|y|<b\}$, $\partial \Omega=\{(x, y):|x|=a~or~|y|=b\}$, $\Omega_0$ is a local subset of $\Omega$ reflecting the fact that the initial disturbance $u^0(x, y)$ has compact support.
If $\Omega$ is big enough compared with $\Omega_0$ and $t$ is not sufficiently large, $\Omega$ is divided into a regular, rectangular grid with node points $\left(x_n, y_m\right)$
$$x_n=-a+(n-1) h,~~  n=1,2, \ldots, N$$
$$y_m=-b+(m-1) k,~~  m=1,2, \ldots, M$$
where $h=(2 a) /(N-1)$ and $k=(2 b) /(M-1)$
Writing $t_p=p \tau$, $p=1,2, \ldots$, where $\tau>0$ is the time step, we can then discretize $u(x, y, t)$ into
$$u_{n m}^p=u\left(x_n, y_m, t_p\right) .$$
FDM scheme The derivatives of $u$ at the inner node points are approximated by central finite differences which have an accuracy of second order. Then, using the Newtonian forward FDM to integrate with respect to $t$ for the inner node points, we have:
$$u_{n, m}^{p+1}=u_{n, m}^p+\tau{\frac{\lambda_1}{h^2}[u_{n+1, m}^p-2 u_{n, m}^p+u_{n-1, m}^p]\\
+\frac{\lambda_2}{k^2}[u_{n, m+1}^p-2 u_{n, m}^p+u_{n, m-1}^p]
+\mu u_{n, m}^p(1-u_{n, m}^p)},n=2, \ldots, N-1 \quad m=2, \ldots, M-1$$
For the boundary condition , we should use
$$u_{1, m}^{p+1}=u_{N, m}^{p+1}=0,  m=1,2, \ldots, M $$
$$u_{n, 1}^{p+1}=u_{n, M}^{p+1}=0,  n=1,2, \ldots, N $$.

and my question is about speed of propagation ,the authors suggest one way which i didnt understand  which is the folowing:


It might be that calling it "FDM" puts slightly more emphasis on being the most trivial multi-step method, while "Euler method" is slightly more associated with it being the most trivial one-step or Runge-Kutta method.

@Lutz Lehmann is there a way to havve approximate spped of propagation of solution ( numerically) based on this scheme ,the authors suggest one but i didnt understand it

I'm not quite sure what you mean with speed of propagation. There is one limitation as each timestep propagates the influence of a given location only to its spacial neighbors, limiting the speed to dx/dt. If that is smaller than the phase speed of the exact equation, you get a totally wrong solution.

i mean speed associated to traveling waves,@Lutz Lehmann
